# Bubble sort in C using pointers

Tags: c

I tried to write a code that uses pointers for bubble sort. 
It gives no errors to me, but as a result generates random digits or "Segmentation fault" message.
Could you please review my code and say where do I go wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * input(int n);
void print(int *ptr, int n);
int * bubble_sort(int *ptr, int n);
void swap(int *a,int *b);

int main(){
        int n;

        printf("Enter the number of the elements to be sorted:\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);


        int *ptr;
        ptr = input(n);
        print(ptr,n);

        int *ptr_sort;

        ptr_sort = bubble_sort(ptr,n);
//      bubble_sort(ptr,n);
        print(ptr_sort,n);
//      print(ptr,n);

        return 0;
}

int * input(int n){
        int i;
        int array[n];

        int *ptr;

        ptr = array;


        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                printf("Enter element %d value: \n", i+1);
                scanf("%d",ptr+i);
        }

        return ptr;
}

void print(int *ptr, int n){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%d\t",*(ptr+i));
        printf("\n");
}

int * bubble_sort(int *ptr, int n){
        int i,j;

        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
                for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
                        if(*(ptr+j)>*(ptr+j+1))
                                swap((ptr+j),(ptr+j+1));

        return ptr;
}

void swap(int *a,int *b){
        int tmp;
        tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
}
```

I tried some debugging with valgrid(which I am not very with) and I received the following information just after the first print finishes:

```
==2318== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2318==    at 0x400803: bubble_sort (ex18_buble_sort.c:58)
==2318==    by 0x40065D: main (ex18_buble_sort.c:21)
==2318==
==2318== Invalid write of size 4
==2318==    at 0x40088F: swap (ex18_buble_sort.c:68)
==2318==    by 0x40083B: bubble_sort (ex18_buble_sort.c:59)
==2318==    by 0x40065D: main (ex18_buble_sort.c:21)
==2318==  Address 0xf0000000f is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

And a lot of other messages after this one, but I guess everything starts from here. So most probably the issue is somewhere in bubble_sort function.

Please help!

Comment: `int array[n];` is a local array that will be destroyed once the execution of the function `input` ends. Fixes for it include using a global array, dynamically allocating memory for it and using `static int array[n];`

Comment: Simply replacing the array definition with `int *array = malloc(n * sizeof(int));` seems to fix all the invalid read/write operations reported by `valgrind`. You'll have to also `free` it though ...

Answer (score 1):

On first glance I see two problems with your code:

```
        int array[n];
```

Thats a local array. You will have to declare that array outside of your input function in order to continue using it from other functions.

Secondly, in your bubblesort function you do comparisons outside of the defined array (if you actually define it, currently, there is nothing, so it points to garbage and works with garbage only)

Comment: `VLA`s are not allowed to be `static`: `error: storage size of ‘array’ isn’t constant` is the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of bubble sort using pointers.

```
void exchange(unsigned long *a, unsigned long *b)
{
    unsigned long cache = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = cache;
}

void bubble_sort(unsigned long *numray, int n)
{

    unsigned long varhold, c, d;

    for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
        for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
            if (*(numray + d) > *(numray + d + 1)) {
                exchange((numray + d), (numray + d + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to save some trouble, here is that inside of a "driver" test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_array(unsigned long *, int);
void exchange(unsigned long *, unsigned long *);
void bubble_sort(unsigned long *, int);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    unsigned long c = 0;
    unsigned long elements = 10000;
    unsigned long *numray = malloc(elements * sizeof(unsigned long));

    srandom(time(NULL));
    for (; c < elements ; c++)
        numray[c] = (random () % 9999999999) * 1000000000000000000;

    print_array(numray, elements);
    printf("====================\n");
    bubble_sort(numray, elements);
    print_array(numray, elements);

    return 0;
}

void bubble_sort(unsigned long *numray, int n)
{

    unsigned long varhold, c, d;

    for (c = 0 ; c < n - 1; c++) {
        for (d = 0 ; d < (n - c - 1) ; d++) {
            if (*(numray + d) > *(numray + d + 1)) {
                exchange((numray + d), (numray + d + 1));
            }
        }
    }

}


void exchange(unsigned long *a, unsigned long *b)
{
    unsigned long cache = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = cache;
}


void print_array(unsigned long *a, int b)
{
    int c;
    for (c=0 ; c < b ; c++)
        printf("%lu\n", a[c]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:(**some change of your code**)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int n);
void print(int *ptr, int n);
void bubble_sort(int *ptr, int n);
void swap(int *a,int *b);

int main(){
        int n;

        printf("Enter the number of the elements to be sorted:\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        input(n);
        return 0;
}

void input(int n){
        int i;
        int array[n];

        int *ptr;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                printf("Enter element %d value: \n", i+1);
                scanf("%d",&array[i]);
        }
        print(array,n);//before sort
        bubble_sort(array,n);
        print(array,n);//after sort
}

void print(int *ptr, int n){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%d\t",*(ptr+i));
        printf("\n");
}

void bubble_sort(int *ptr, int n){
        int i,j;

        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
                for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
                        if(*(ptr+j)>*(ptr+j+1))
                                swap((ptr+j),(ptr+j+1));
}

void swap(int *a,int *b){
        int tmp;
        tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Works! But my initial idea was to use main to call input,print and bubble_sort. So, it looks like the big mistake I did was the way i wrote input function. It works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my bubble_sort function, but it continued to generate random numbers while array was declared as local array within input function. Once I declared it in main everything went to normal.

Thanks for your comments and help!